# Typeorm: Find entity with relations and where condition

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm working with typeorm and using repository to load entities. I want to find property and its active tenants **(is_active = true)**

In PropertyTenant model, I have:

```
@ManyToOne(type => Property)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'property_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
property: Property;
```

And in property model, I have:

```
@OneToMany(
    () => PropertyTenant, (propertyTenant: PropertyTenant) => propertyTenant.property
)
propertyTenants: PropertyTenant[];
```

I tried something like this:

```
return await propertyRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                id: id,
                'propertyTenants.is_active': true
            },
            relations: [
                'location', 'location.city', 'location.city.state', 'propertyPurpose', 'propertyAmenities', 'propertyAmenities.amenity',
                'propertyTenants', 'propertyTenants.tenant', 'propertyType', 'propertyDocuments', 'propertyDocuments.documentType', 'propertyImages'
            ]
        });
```

It gives the error:

```
No entity column \"propertyTenants.is_active\" was found.
```

I'm not able to find anything in documentation. I don't want to use query build as it returns raw data and I need to process it.

Is there a way in which I can put condition in @OneToMany or @ManyToOne?

How to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is to use `QueryBuilder`. You state you don't want to use it because it returns raw results, but only functions like `QueryBuilder.execute()` will return raw results. `.getOne()` and `.getMany()` will return results in entity format, just like you would get with `Repository.findOne()`.